# problems with the external network

Tags: raspbian, web-server

I was able to use the site with the name that I put in the no-ip locally until I go to move the ssl certificates and the port configurations in my router and simply stop, nor by the ip of it enters the page

on my router the port is set to

```
name: Web-Server
start / end: 80/80
ip: 192.168.1.148
protocol: tcp and udp
```

installed:

```
apache2
php
mysql
```

if any data is missing just ask.

Error entering page: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Edit:on the local network no longer works

Comment: What is no-ip? For what do you need ssl certificates? Why do you fiddle with ports on your router? What external network do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using https then you need to open the `port 443/tcp`

do not forget open the ports on your `firewall` too

[list of known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Comment: still giving the same problem

Comment: I suspect it's something on ssl or router

Comment: what is what you want to accomplish? you have a lamp within your pi and you want to access it with a domain name within your LAN? or you want to make it available from anywhere?

Comment: I want to make it available to anyone anywhere